# Does the sequence $(a_n)$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)$ be any real sequence. Let $C = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}: x \textrm{ is a possible limit to a subsequence of }(a_n)\}$. If the size of $C$ is 1 (thus $|C|=1$), then is it sufficient to $(a_n)$ be convergent? If no, then why?

Comment: What does "is a possible limit of" mean? It has a limit or it doesn't.

Comment: I edited the question. $C$ is a set of all possible limits $x$ of all subsequence of $(a_n)$.

Comment: Hint: what happens if some subsequences diverge to $+\infty$ ?

Comment: No,  take for instance 1 for even integer and n for odds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(a_n)=(1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,....)$ then $C=\{1\}$, but $(a_n) $ is divergent.